# iOS 8.0 breaks async keyword for external JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, ios, asynchronous

Loading external JavaScripts with the "async" keyword is not working correctly in iOS 8.0

(The keyword "defer" seems to work correct.)

Do any one else see this problem with "async" on iOS 8.0?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: <script src="enter_whatever_you_want.js" async=async"></script>

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean a reproducible example I can try on my phone (I have iOS8)

Comment: I'll try and setup an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing I can see that this problem is related to the HTML5 video tag in combination with loading a JavaScript on the same webpage using the "async" keyword.

I can not figure out what exactly the bug is but it might have something to do with how the video is loaded.

Setting the "preload" attribut to "metadata" instead of "none" the bug is fixed for some reason.

But when this bug manifest itself the "readystatechange" will not be fired if the script has been loaded with the "async" keyword.

The only waterproof solution today is to use "the "defer" keyword instead of "async".